# MySQL process uses more than 100% CPU usage and need about 1 GB of memory

Tags: mysql, memory, process, cpu

I am running MySQL server on the server's which has following specifications -

Dual Xeon Quad Core 2.0, 2048 MB RAM, 1x 160 GB SATA
Fedora Core + SSH

But MySQL process for inserting 10000 records take more than 100% of CPU and up to 1 GB of RAM.
It's a plain insert statement.

Why is MySQL is taking so much of memory and what can done about it?.

Comment: Not enough information to answer and probably belongs on serverfault.com

Comment: Please post your schema and the insert statement.

Comment: Sorry jitter. If I posted on wrong forum. 
These are the details :-
Use Test1;
Insert into Customer(FirstName, LastName, CountryID, Address, Phone)
Select FirstName, LastName, CountryID, Address, Phone From Test2.Customer
Where UserID Between 1 and 5000 and CustomerID in (Select CustId from Cust_Details Where CustName like 'Mi%');

Comment: Sure more than 100% is due to multiple processes/threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heaviest part in your query is the SELECT:

```
Select FirstName, LastName, CountryID, Address, Phone
From Test2.Customer
Where UserID Between 1 and 5000
and CustomerID in (Select CustId from Cust_Details Where CustName like 'Mi%')
```

The nested query probably is repeated for each row. You can check this running `EXPLAIN PLAN` + all the SELECT query. I guess the 'like' operator is used against a non-indexed column. In this case (`like 'xyz%'`) a simple index can improve performance a lot.

[Added: moreover, SELECT CustId ... must output id's that are greater than 5000, that aren't needed at all. A composite index (CustId, CustName) on Cust_Details must also be useful.]

Try usign a join instead:

```
Select FirstName, LastName, CountryID, Address, Phone
From Test2.Customer c, Cust_Details cd
Where c.UserID Between 1 and 5000
and c.CustomerID=cd.CustId
and left(cd.CustName) = 'Mi'
```